# File is not readed completely by Copy Data in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm developing a pipeline that be able to insert data from a .txt file located in the Blob Storage into a table in a SQL Data Base.

Problem: Somehow the activity configuration is not working properly cause' is not reading all the records in the file and in consequence is not loading all the data into the Data Base (I realized this issue when I opened the file and compared the number of records from .text file against SQL table. Also, when I searched records from the last month in the table on SQL I didn't find them)

Comment: you can see, the Number of rows copied to sink metric "does not apply when copying files as-is without parsing them, for example, when source and sink datasets are binary format type, or other format type with identical settings." I just had the copy activity fail and still shows Rows written: 266,206

Comment: Can you share the sink dataset configuration, how you specified the table name since auto create table is selected

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT could you explain me a little bit more about how did you get to load the data properly? Also, I've updating the post and added the Sink Dataset Configuration Screenshot

Comment: And what I meant in the first comment is, even though the copy activity fails, the pipeline run details shows the rows written number same as rows read, but actual rows copied wont be same

Comment: I have followed the exact same configuration as you have, i've set DISTRIBUTION = HASH (description), CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX. Data written: 28.054 MB Rows written: 266,206 Are you importing schema automatically or manually mapping

Comment: Also I've applied the Clustered Columnstore Index as you and I got same issue, but when you said all the stuff about importing schema automatically or manually I realized that the Copy Data activity is not updating the file because I set it up the schema Manually, so i think that is the error because when I imported the schema again I could load the data properly. So, the question now is, how Can I import the schema automatically?

Comment: By default it would be empty. You would have to go In the mapping section of copy activity, click on Import schema before copying. Same can be done at both source and sink dataset properties.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, while using copy activity you would have to make sure to set the schema before running the activity. By design the schema mapping is left empty and has to be configured by the user either manually or asking adf to import the schema from the dataset.

> **Note:** While using Auto create table option in sink, *it automatically creates sink table (if nonexistent) in source schema*,
> but *won't be supported when a stored procedure is specified (on the
> sink side) or when staging is enabled.*

[image]

Using COPY statement to load data into Azure Synapse Analytics as sink, the connector supports automatically creating destination table with DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN if not exists based on the source schema.

Refer official doc: [Copy and transform data in Azure Synapse Analytics by using Azure Data Factory or Synapse pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory#use-copy-statement)

Source...

[image]

Sink...

[image]

So Azure Synapse will be used as the sink. Additionally, an Azure Synapse table has to be created which matches the column names, column order, and column data types of source.

[image]

[image]

### For dynamic mapping

If you view the pipeline code, you can see in the `Translator` section the JSON equivalent of the mapping section from UI.

[image]

You can reuse this as a base in Dynamic mapping to enable further copying similar files without having to manually configure schema.

[image]

Copy the JSON under mappings in translator

[image]

[image]

[image]